# the field type can have these values 1,2,3..10. how to count the records of the highest frequent value of type

Tags: mysql

I think it says it clearly in the title:
lets assume we have this table called `realestate`:

```
 id     type
  1      4
  2      5
  3      5
  4      1
  5      4
  6      4
```

I want the output to be `type=4` because it's the highest frequent type and I want it to output the frequency of the previous type which is here `count=3`

Comment: man!! this really is a brain cracking question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `type`, COUNT(1) AS `count`
FROM `realestate`
GROUP BY `type`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Example - http://www.sqlize.com/817Dtyd4KD